# Search option in Crashlytics/Firebase where I can search by the name of the crash?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Is there search option in Crashlytics/Firebase where I can search by name of the crash like for example

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 3

Now is there search option where if I search for `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY`, then I got all the errors containing that.

I have searched everywhere but didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-on from Mike Bonnell's answer, once you've linked Firebase to BigQuery, you'll want to run something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `com.example.yourpackage`
WHERE exceptions.exception_message CONTAINS "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY"
```

A full list of Crashlytics BigQuery export fields are [available in the docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484).

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase here. You can [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery) Big Query and Firebase Crashlytics in order to get full custom search or data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it would be a lot easier for the developers if this kind of search was provided directly.

Comment: I'll share the feedback with the team.

Comment: Please do, I simply cannot understand how a crash reporting tool doesn't support full-text-search on the website… it makes Crash handling in a big app, kind of noisier, repetitive, generates duplicates, makes it impossible to find similar (but likely related) issues, etc. It's so bad like this, that I'm simply recommending we switch to another tool and remove Firebase from the android app; QE is driven nuts by the inability to search. I get that FBase is much more than a crash tool… but it wasn't me the one who integrated it to begin with… it was google. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, much appreciated @MartinMarconcini. It's interesting as Fabric didn't support full text search either. There was different functionality, but we often heard complains about it not finding what devs wanted which is one of the reasons why we added the fully custom search in BigQuery.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Agree that Fabric didn't have it either and it was one of my complains at them since forever. As apps become more and more complex, crashes that are completely related may manifest themselves in completely different ways, and being able to search for certain keywords is the _key_ (no pun intended) to finding a solution or at least isolate it. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBonnell It is really frustrating not being able to search by Exception Name in crashlytics. We had to move from Google Analytics to crashlytics and we were really disappointed that one of the most helpful tool feature in google analytics was not available here.!! Please integrate this feature. Its been an year since this answer.

Comment: @Ashu I'd recommend reviewing the Stack Overflow Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language I no longer work on Firebase or Crashlytics, but reviewing their public roadmap: https://get.fabric.io/roadmap indicates that "Search by issue title and subtitle" and "Search by User" are available in Firebase Crashlytics. If those don't fit your need, I'd recommend reaching out to the Firebase support team.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I don't know why, but I am really sorry if you felt like I used unfriendly language but I did't mean to in anyway. Anyways, crashlytics still doesn't have that option so I have integrated with BigQuery as you suggested. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Google Analytics was able to search without a problem, try now in Crashlytics to search all crashes with some word in the stack trace, it doesn't work!